# Automate weekly emails with same attachment name to list of recipients

Tags: microsoft-outlook, microsoft-office, automation, office365

Is it possible to automatically send weekly emails to list of recipients with the same attachment name? E.g., if I have a document "report.pdf" in a specified directory. The contents of the report is updated on a daily basis but the name is always the same.

Looked around for a while but didn't find any method to do this yet. Was only able to find ways to automatically send text emails without attachments.

I'm using Outlook for Office 365.

Comment: You can't out of the box. Only using VBA/programming or third-party tools/addins.

Comment: Other considerations: what happens if outlook is closed? How is the report being generated? It might be easier to extend that process to send the email? If you're happy with a more manual process setting up a shortcut in Outlook to create a new email to your known group...

Answer (score 2):

Do you also have access to OneDrive, OneDrive for Business, Dropbox, etc?

If yes - you can do the following

1. Sign up for Microsoft Flow with your Office 365 ID (
   https://flow.microsoft.com/en-us/ )
2. Go to "My Flows" and create a new flow from Template, and use the
   "Send OneDrive files to an email" template.
3. Customize the template how you need it to work.

Now when you drop a new file in the designated folder (same name or not) it will send an email with the attachment.

If you need to have the email generated and pick up the file from a local FileShare - that's more difficult as there are no "connectors" that you can use to reach that.  You have to use some sort of scripting or Macro to assist with automating that request. If that is what you are looking for let me know and I can drop a PowerShell script in here to show you how to do it.